# Log buffer beyond 8k on WAS Liberty Profile

Tags: websphere-liberty, open-liberty

I am writing one json payload per line in Liberty console (do not use any third party library) and collect them in LogDNA. This is working fine as long as payload is smaller than 8k. Beyond this the json payload is cut with a new line and can not be processed in LogDNA.
Is there any liberty setting to go beyond this limit ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be for a couple of known reasons.  (I see that you are not using a 3rd party library, but I'm including both reasons for completeness in case others are looking for causes of this).

1. Log4J -
   If you're creating logs with an older version of Log4J, using the Console Appender, it will break your log entries into 8k chunks before it writes them to System.out (see https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/14197).  Switching to a newer version of log4J would fix this.
2. Liberty -
   If you're using an older version of WebSphere Liberty / Open Liberty (before 19.0.0.5) and writing logs to the console they were broken into 8k chunks (see https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/6095). Switching to a newer version of Liberty would fix this.

Comment: For the record, we were able to reproduce the problem with latest version. We were using JUL ConsoleHandler that was introducing this 8K buffering. Using JUL Handler directly remove the problem.